# mongoimport returns (imported 0 documents) on basic CSV file

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport, database

I have a very basic CSV, basically just 3 columns and 3 rows of gibberish. I run the Mongoimport command to a database on MongoLab and get this in return:

```
$mongoimport -h ds033145.mongolab.com:33145 -d medical_data -c medical_data -u medical_data -p medical_data --file new.csv --type csv  --file new.csv --headerline
2015-12-16T13:23:57.562-0600    connected to: ds033145.mongolab.com:33145
2015-12-16T13:23:57.631-0600    imported 0 documents
```

here is the CSV file:

```
aada    bddd    cdfasf
ddasf   edafa   fasdfsa
gda     hdad    idada
```

What gives? I checked MongoLab and there is nothing in the database.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a couple of sample rows of your CSV file please?

Comment: sure, I was just testing the mongoimport command with a very small file, ill post it...